# Runtime Exception when cordova app is run on xcode

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cordova-plugins, xcode10.1

I have created a cordova project and added ios platform , am using cordova-plugin-firebase-database from chemerisuk to have javascript based platfrom to connect to firebase-database, the build for xcode succeeds however when run on emulator it causes the exception  . 
cordova-plugin-firebase is the base plugin for corodova-plugin-firebase-database, however as there are no firbase database related services in this plugin hence am using cordova-plugin-firebase-database.

i am using GoogleService-Info.plist s, and i have Linked the  object linker after referring to the firebase website ->$(OTHER_LDFLAGS) -ObjC in to the xcode.
I have cleaned the workspace and deleted the build files which was suspected to be the cause for this error , but even then it didnt workout.

I am getting the below error.

2019-02-07 16:58:16.810031+0900 HelloCordova[11898:1643374] +[FIRApp registerAsConfigurable:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1080dfdc0
2019-02-07 16:58:16.812181+0900 HelloCordova[11898:1643374] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[FIRApp registerAsConfigurable:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1080dfdc0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109dea1bb **exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108bcc735 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109e08e44 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109deeed6 ___forwarding_** + 1446
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109df0da8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108bcdf85 call_load_methods + 705
    6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108bcec04 load_images + 77
    7   ???                                 0x00000001082ba068 0x0 + 4432044136
    8   ???                                 0x00000001082c77a2 0x0 + 4432099234
    9   ???                                 0x00000001082c6974 0x0 + 4432095604
    10  ???                                 0x00000001082c6a08 0x0 + 4432095752
    11  ???                                 0x00000001082ba388 0x0 + 4432044936
    12  ???                                 0x00000001082be497 0x0 + 4432061591
    13  ???                                 0x00000001082b9624 0x0 + 4432041508
    14  ???                                 0x000000010b0c22c4 0x0 + 4480312004
    15  ???                                 0x000000010b0c014f 0x0 + 4480303439
    16  ???                                 0x000000010b0bb4f6 0x0 + 4480283894
    17  ???                                 0x000000010b0bb036 0x0 + 4480282678
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException